# How to use org.netbeans.swing.outline?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, outline

I've heard of the package mentioned above, but i couldn't find a Download. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the latest NetBeans IDE development build from netbeans.org and there is a jar: org-netbeans-swing-outline.jar somewhere.

Comment: It's in the platform\modules folder.

Comment: In latest source release (v12) in the `platform/o.n.swing.outline`. You can compile them directly to a jar, without any other dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

According to [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/swing_outline_component), all you need is the most recent build of Netbeans.